# netbeans jquery breakpoint ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, debugging, netbeans

I have a netbeans 7.4 (also tried 7.3) PHP/javascript that refuses to breakpoint in jquery ajax loaded pages that contain included javascript.  It works fine for PHP and even for top level javascript but not for example with:

index.php:

```
<script> src="js/test.js"></script>
```

js/test.js

```
$("#container").load("pages/ajaxtest.php");
```

pages/ajaxtest.php:

```
<script src="js/ajaxedjs.js"></script>
```

js/ajaxedjs.js:

```
alert("hello");
```

The code works fine, but i can never breakpoint in the debugger environment inside the ajaxedjs.js.

I noticed that chrome is trying to load ajaxed.js?=12321333 which is obviously the caching mechanims.  Does this need disabling and if so how?

already tried:

```
- set source mapping in netbeans to localhost\mywebsite -> c:\wamp\www\mywebsite
- disable/enable caching in dev tools chrome
- installed netbeans connector for chrome
- check xdebug settings as per other posts
```

I realise i can use 'debugger;' and use chrome itself, but this is surely not optimal when netbeans provides integrated debugging?  Can anyone shed any light or offer a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the loading using $().load and if it will work (perhaps you can try some dummy JS code), but the dynamic parameter is for sure problem. Try to load() JS code without it.

The caching parameter is the problem has been reported [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=229383). You need to disable it but you didn't specified who/what is appending the parameter so without that, I can't really tell you how to disable it. You can load the page and after that create a breakpoint but it will work only until you reload the page. Then URL will be different and this breakpoint stop working.

BTW If you use Chrome Developer Tools for debugging, it has the same problem. If you add breakpoint to the loaded script with dynamic URL parameter, it will work only until you reload page, after reload parameter is different and breakpoint won't be hit because URL has changed.